# vector initialization in c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Can someone explain to me why verticies.size() in Graph constructor equals '4' but when called again in addEdge verticies.size() equals 0?  The program crashes at verticies[fromVertex].addEdge(toVertex) because the size of verticies is 0.

I'm sure this is something I should know, but I don't where I am going wrong.

```
class Vertex {

public:
    int value;
    vector<int> adj;
    bool isVisited = false;

    Vertex(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    void addEdge(int destination)
    {
        adj.push_back(destination);
    }   
};

class Graph
{

public:

    int vertexCount;    // No. of vertices            
    vector<Vertex> verticies;

    Graph(int _vertexCount)
    {
        this->vertexCount = _vertexCount;
        vector<Vertex> verticies;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _vertexCount; i++)
        {
            Vertex v = Vertex(i);
            verticies.push_back(v);
        }
        cout << "verticies count " << verticies.size() << endl;
    }
    void addEdge(int fromVertex, int toVertex)  
    {
        cout << "verticies count in addEdge: " << verticies.size() << endl;
        verticies[fromVertex].addEdge(toVertex); 
    }
    void findPath(int fromVertex, int toVertex, vector<int> pathSoFar)  
    {
        pathSoFar.push_back(fromVertex);
        if (fromVertex == toVertex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pathSoFar.size(); i++)
            {
               cout << pathSoFar.at(i) << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < verticies[fromVertex].adj.size(); i++)
            {   
                int nextToVisit = verticies[fromVertex].adj.at(i);
                if (verticies[nextToVisit].isVisited == false)
                {
                    findPath(nextToVisit, toVertex, pathSoFar);
                }

            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3, 3);


    vector<int> path;
    g.findPath(2, 1, path);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You create local variable with same name (`verticies`) than your member in `Graph`

Comment: `vector<Vertex> verticies;` in your constructor body is making a new local vector that shadows your member named `verticies`. That's what you are initializing.

Answer (score 7):

> Can someone explain to me why verticies.size() in Graph constructor
>   equals '4' but when called again in addEdge verticies.size() equals 0?

This is because those are two different objects. Here

```
Graph(int _vertexCount)
{
    this->vertexCount = _vertexCount;
    vector<Vertex> verticies;
    // ....
}
```

You are creating a local vector called `verticies` that shadows the member variable. Simply removing that line should be fine. I mean you already declared the member, no need to do it twice ;).

Moreoever, I would suggest you to either resize the vector before filling it with data, or at least reserve to the capacity you need.

Comment: does shadowing prompt a warning?

Comment: Depends on what and how you shadow. Member variables, usually no.

Comment: @codekaizer *guaranteed* to generate a warning? No, since it's perfectly valid to shadow variables according to the language spec. *Can* generate a warning? Yes. With the right compiler flags - for GCC, look up `-Wshadow` (and friends).

Answer (score 1):

Here you are shadowing your class field:

```
Graph(int _vertexCount)
{
    this->vertexCount = _vertexCount;
    vector<Vertex> verticies;  // <--- exactly here
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _vertexCount; i++)
    {
        Vertex v = Vertex(i);
        verticies.push_back(v);
    }
    cout << "verticies count " << verticies.size() << endl;
}
```

And you are doing all the operations on the local (in the context of the constructor) `verticies` instead of `Graph::verticies`. BTW, correct English plural form is `vertices`.